# oozie > coordinator > how to trigger action with external event

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

In Oozie site, it was told "Commonly, workflow jobs are run based on regular time intervals and/or data availability. And, in some cases, they can be triggered by an external event."
Anyone has any idea about how to trigger action with external event?

Answer (score 1):

External Event can be availability of file in some directory.
So oozie coordinator has this facility.This is useful when you need to trigger second workflow on completion of first dependent workflow.
Second cordinator keeps on polling for availability of success_trigger.txt in 
triggerdirpath

triggerdirpath is hdfs path where success_trigger.txt is created by first workflow

```
<coordinator-app name="Xxx" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" start="${startTime2}" end="${endTime}" timezone="GMT-0700" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.2">


        <dataset name="check_for_SUCCESS" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" initial-instance="${startTime2}" timezone="GMT-0700">
                <uri-template>${triggerdirpath}</uri-template>
                <done-flag>success_trigger.txt</done-flag>
            </dataset>
    </datasets>

    <input-events>
        <data-in name="check_for_SUCCESS_data" dataset="check_for_SUCCESS">
        <instance>${startTime2}</instance>
        </data-in>
      </input-events>


    <action>
        <workflow>
            <app-path>${WF_path}</app-path>
            <configuration>
                <property><name>WaitForThisInputData</name><value>${coord:dataIn('check_for_SUCCESS_data')}</value></property>
                <property><name>WhenToStart</name><value>${startTime2}</value></property>
                <property><name>rundate</name><value>${coord:dataOut('currentFullDate')}</value></property>
                <property><name>previousdate</name><value>${coord:dataOut('previousFullDate')}</value></property>
                <property><name>currentyear</name><value>${coord:dataOut('currentYear')}</value></property>
                <property><name>currentmonth</name><value>${coord:dataOut('currentMonth')}</value></property>
                <property><name>currentday</name><value>${coord:dataOut('currentDay')}</value></property>
                <property><name>previousbatchtime</name><value>${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(),-1,'DAY'),"yyyy-MM-dd")}</value></property>
                <property><name>currentbatchtime</name><value>${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(),0,'DAY'),"yyyy-MM-dd")}</value></property>
                <property><name>nextbatchtime</name><value>${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(),1,'DAY'),"yyyy-MM-dd")}</value></property>
            </configuration>
        </workflow>
    </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! But the workflow ${WF_path} has to use the property WaitForThisInputData right? For instance in the decision node. Otherwise Oozie tiself probably does not check the existence of success_trigger.txt at all. At least I tried the similar with. The workflow is always executed anyway with regardless of the existence of success_trigger.txt

Comment: Sorry that I used the ${coord:current(0)} in the "instance" node, but it did not work at all. Then I tried to use ${startTime2} as you suggested and it worked. What is the reason for ${coord:current(0)} not work?

Comment: It has nothing do with start time of coordinator. Coordinator will be triggered at specified time  , but it will be in waiting state until and unless it finds success_trigger.txt in specified hdfs directory . So the workflow ${WF_path} will not be triggered. For more clarity you can refer https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.6.1._coord:currentint_n_EL_Function_for_Synchronous_Datasets